# Accurate timing with NSDateComponents

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nscalendar

I am trying to build a countdown, which displays the amount of seconds to go.

The example below is set to 10 seconds, but the output is 8 seconds.

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *finishDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:10 sinceDate:currentDate];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSSecondCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit| NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit
                                           fromDate:currentDate
                                             toDate:finishDate
                                            options:0];
NSInteger hour_ = [components hour];   
NSInteger minute_ = [components minute];
NSInteger second_ = [components second];
```

Log

```
currentDate = 2012-06-05 03:13:10 +0000
finishDate_ = 2012-06-05 03:13:19 +0000
second_ = 8
```

Comment: Note that this isn't really "timing" but more date calculations...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just copied and pasted your code.
I added these lines to the bottom:

```
NSLog(@"%@", currentDate);
NSLog(@"%@", finishDate);
NSLog(@"%d, %d, %d", hour_, minute_, second_);
```

It worked perfectly, using Xcode 4.3.2 on the iPad simulator running iOS 5.1:

```
2012-06-05 00:19:34.341 Testing App[59813:fb03] 2012-06-05 04:19:34 +0000
2012-06-05 00:19:34.342 Testing App[59813:fb03] 2012-06-05 04:19:44 +0000
2012-06-05 00:19:34.343 Testing App[59813:fb03] 0, 0, 10
```

Are you using different versions?

Comment: I'm using exactly those versions. What about the current & finish date?

Comment: The reality is that this code is a simplified version of what is actually happening. I copied the code above and got the same result as you, so there must be something to do with the time taken to perform other tasks that is causing the offset.

Comment: Well, taking extra time for calculations shouldn't matter since you are adding time to the starting value. This is simple math....